# Problems with Nexus Repository Manager with docker

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype

I have a problem with docker and the nexus repository manager,
if i use my domain with ssl certificates i get this error in the console:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://nexus.domain.de/nexus/#view-repositories' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://nexus.domain.de/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/?isLocal&_dc=1686905795208'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

In the interface i get this "There was an error communicating with the server: request timed out."

If I only use the IP without the domain everything works perfectly!